# QTimer runs after Dialog has been closed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I have a **QDialog**, where i create a **QTimer Object**, which triggers every **n** seconds a function. After closing the Dialog (hitting the x button), the timer is still firing and seems to be not destroyed. How can i stop it? Currently as a workaround i am explicitly calling **Qtimer.stop()** when entering the  **closeEvent()**?

I would expect that every class-member is deleted, when the Window is closed, even when i call the **Deconstructor** explicitly, the Qtimer object persists.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys



def update():
    print "tick..."

class Main(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)


        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(update)
        self.timer.start(2000)

        # scroll area
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)

        # main layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()


        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)


    def closeEvent(self, evt):
        print "class event called"
        self.timer.stop()

myWidget = Main()
myWidget.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/timers.html

> The main API for the timer functionality is `QTimer`. That class
>   provides regular timers that emit a signal when the timer fires, and
>   inherits `QObject` so that it fits well into the ownership structure of
>   most GUI programs. The normal way of using it is like this:
>
> ```
> QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
> connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateCaption()));
> timer->start(1000);
> ```
>
> The `QTimer` object is made into a child of this widget so that, when
>   this widget is deleted, the timer is deleted too. Next, its `timeout()`
>   signal is connected to the slot that will do the work, it is started
>   with a value of 1000 milliseconds, indicating that it will time out
>   every second.

In C++, the timers are parented to the widget or another `QObject`, and then their lifespan is tied to the lifespan of the `QObject`, but it is still good practice to stop a timer when you don't need it.  The layouts get parented when you call `setLayout`.  The timer doesn't know its parent so it doesn't get destroyed when the widget gets destroyed.  It just sits on the heap, still getting ran by the `QApplication` event loop.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setParent

So either pass in self to the constructor of the `QTimer`, or call `setParent` on the `QTimer` to set it into the object tree properly.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html

UPDATE: Apparently `setParent` isn't working in PyQt. Just pass in `self` in the `QTimer` constructor.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i tried the setParent(self) and setParent(self.parent) but it didn't work. Is there anything i missunderstood?

Comment: @user1767754 You probably also need to set the [`Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) attribute of the dialog so that the dialog (and it's children) are actually deleted.

Comment: Actually setting: self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self) solved the issue, setParent was freezing. If you can incorporate this into your answer i will  mark it as correct answer. thanks for your help though.

Comment: Can confirm, you have to do both: a) `self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)` and b) `self.timer = QTimer(self)`. The `self` in QTimer sets the parent to the current instance of the app.